# State of a bound parameter in a promise

Tags: javascript, state, lifecycle, page-lifecycle

I'm curious about the timing when I bind something to a promise.

```
var that = this;
function p(){

    var promise = new Promise(
        function (yes, no) {
        /* ....  */
        /* ....  */
        }).then(function (val) {
        /* ....  */
        /* ....  */
        }.bind(this));
}.bind(this)
```

Will the condition

```
that === this
```

allways return true, considering that the scope outside the promise is async and `.then` might be resolved way later in the lifecycle.

In other words, will `this` have the same value as when the first function was called, or will it have the value as it is actually used in the `.then` part?

Comment: Where do you place that condition in your code? If you are curious about multiple places, please mark them explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by what is to the left of the dot in the calling method. If you're not calling a method of an object, then `this` will be the global (window in browser).

In your example the line `var that = this` sets the value of that to that global variable window (or global). So in this specific case, this would always equal that. However that is due to a side effect, if you used a different object as `this`, then in

```
function (yes, no) {
    /* ....  */
    /* ....  */
}
```

`this !== that`

I'm made a little fiddle as an example 
http://jsfiddle.net/metaf0x9/

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the `then` function, `that === this`. This is true because of the `bind` function.

Inside of the promise function, it's not possible to tell what the value of `this` will be, but it will *not* be `that`.

The reason is that we do not know the context in which the function will be called. This function is not bound to `that`, so we know it will not be the `this` object.  The `this` object could be global, or it could be bound to something else through a `bind` or `call` invocation. In that case, `this` would be different.

Comment: …but you don't really know what `that` is either, it could be (and likely is) the global object as well.

Comment: Good point! I just made the assumption that it wasn't, otherwise, this wouldn't be a particularly interesting question.